# How to find the latest version of redis-server in repos?

Tags: package-management

I need to learn how to search for packages for 'redis-server' and also what version they various repo's have?

I know to add a repo I add it to /etc/apt/source.list and sometimes I have to add a key.

(btw, why do you have to add a key to fetch from a repo?)

Comment: The key isn't for authorization but instead is a mechanism for verifying the authenticity of the PPA's packages.  Otherwise imagine a scenario where the PPA host was compromised and someone uploaded a rootkit. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/add-apt-key.8.html

Answer (score 37):

You can use the following PPA: https://launchpad.net/~rwky/+archive/redis.

You can install this repo running the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rwky/redis
```

then update the packages' information

```
sudo apt-get update
```

finally install the application

```
sudo apt-get install redis-server
```

Comment: Is adding things from launchpad secure?

Comment: No, not particularly. Anybody can set up a PPA on Launchpad. If you trust (Ubuntu and) that particular Launchpad user, you can be reasonably sure that the packages you download and install are identical to the ones the user uploaded in the first place, but beyond that, there are no guarantees.

Comment: Be warned, this redis-server package changes a few things in the configuration, and isn't a drop in replacement.